# Why is the class passed to a function being called inside a class function when using self in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

So, I have this code snippet.

```
class LogObserver(object): 
    def write_log(...):
        self.logger.log(self, level, message, *args, **kwargs)
...
```

Looking into the debugger and the error messages as well, I noticed that the variable `level` contains `LogObserver` instead of an integer. I was expecting an integer.

However, when I remove `self` from `self.logger.log()` like:

```
self.logger.log(level, message, *args, **kwargs)
```

`level` contains an integer instead of a `LogObserver` object. The error messages disappear as well.

What is the explanation behind this behavior?

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. `self` is the instance; if you include it in that call, then the instance will be passed; if you remove it, it won't. What is your question?

Comment: `self` inside `.log` should refer to the object that's called `self.log` in the `LogObserver`, not the observer itself. Why did you think you needed to pass in the outer `self` (or any explicit instance)? Did you write that snippet? Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: In the first case you pass in self, the LogObserver. In the second you don't. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: @jonrsharpe It was by accident that I included `self` inside `.log`. Error on my part. I removed `self` already in my actual code.

Oddly, the bug piqued my curiosity on why it behaves that way and that is why I posted a question here.

Comment: That was not clear to me from the question. Could you [edit] it to clarify what you want to know?

Comment: Guys, I am sorry for the confusion. I edited the question already. @jonrsharpe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you call an instance method (*not* staticmethod or classmethod), the instance is implicitly passed as the first parameter. That is why method definitions take `self` as the first parameter; the name `self` is just a convention, by the way. For example, `foo.bar()` will be translated to `type(foo).bar(foo)`.

If you *explicitly* pass on the instance as an argument, it will be passed along like any other argument - after the instance is passed in implicitly already. For example, `foo.bar(foo)` will be translated to `type(foo).bar(foo, foo)`.

Now, inside a method, `self` is usually the first parameter. Let's say you have defined

```
class Foo(object):
  def bar(self, other=None):
    pass
foo = Foo()
```

Calling `foo.bar()` is translated to `type(foo).bar(self=foo, other=None)`.
Likewise, `foo.bar(foo)` is translated to `type(foo).bar(self=foo, other=foo)`.

So, when you call `self.logger.log(self, level, message, *args, **kwargs)`, that actually translates to `type(self).logger.log(self=self, level=self, message=level, args=(message,), kwargs={})`. Thus, `level` gets an instance of your object, namely `self`.

---

Note that `foo.bar()` is not always resolved as `type(foo).bar(foo)` - this is only the case if `bar` is only defined on the class/type. The passing of `self` is not changed by this, however.

Comment: From how I understand it, this would be like, `LogObserver`.logger.log(self=self.logger, LogObserver, ...)`. But since I am using `self`, `self=self.logger` is implicitly defined. Am I right?

Comment: @SeanFrancisN.Ballais For the passing of `self=self.logger`, you are spot on. How the *attribute* `self.logger` is resolved depends on whether `logger` is defined on the instance or class. It's close to `instance.__dict__('logger', type(instance).__dict__.get('logger'))`, i.e. will first try the instance, then its class (include base classes).

Comment: Now I get it. Thanks for the insight.